# How do I get Compass' Sass Files

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I'm new to using Compass. I don't know much about ruby and I use Grunt for most of my preprocessing.

I'd like to customize my own version of Compass so I can edit some of the mixins and other Sass related stuff.

Is there a way to generate the Sass files from compass to a folder using ruby? Or are the Sass files from compass stored somewhere on my local disk when I installed it via the ruby gem?

Either way, how can I get the files onto local disk so I can edit them?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to edit Compass?  Is there some reason you couldn't search for the source code?

Comment: I did, I can't find it anywhere though. Which is why I asked here.

Comment: "Find me a 3rd party source/library" is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you´re on a Mac it's in `Library/Ruby/Gems/{ruby-version}/compass-core-{compass-version}/stylesheets/`.

As noted in the comments however it might be better to get it straight from the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/tree/stable/frameworks/compass/stylesheets).